# Why does it take more than 30 seconds for chat activity Messages to return a 200 ("OK") with an empty content?

Tags: liveagent, chatter-rest-api

when I make a Messages request to Live Agent Server by REST API, it returns relatively quick if there are events that occur on the Live Agent server, but it takes more than 30 seconds to return a 200 ("OK") if there are no events. The 30 seconds block my code. Is there way I can control this case in the Settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because it's intended to be a "long polling loop." This means the session remains open for a long time for messages to appear.

> When you start a request, all pending messages will be immediately delivered to your session. If there are no pending messages, the connection to the server will remain open. The connection will return messages continuously as they are received on the server. --[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_http_long_polling_loop.htm)

You should call this method asynchronously to avoid blocking your user interface. You can reduce the timeout of your callout request, but that will cause worse performance in the long run. Without seeing your code, I cannot make a more specific suggestion for you.